# Xcode header mess

Tags: c++, xcode, header

I'm using the rapidjson library for a c++ project - I am writing the project in Xcode. I realise this is a really basic query, but its causing me a major headache!

I have added a couple of external headers files for the JSON library (see below). However, having added these, the  Xcode Symbol Navigator view has filled up with >100 classes, functions, structs, enums etc. Its now impossible to find, or easily see, my functions within this view... Is there a way to hide these external headers? Its completely ruined my already slow productivity :(

(the following are added to one of my header files)

```
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some controls at the bottom of the symbol navigator:

[image: file navigator]

These help you control which symbols are listed in the navigator. The first one, containing a C, shows only classes and protocols, hiding other symbol types like enumerations. The one that looks like a document icon limits the symbols to those defined in your project, so symbols from libraries and other projects are omitted. The one with an M hides methods. And, of course, the search field lets you search the listed symbols for something specific.

Using these controls may help you cut down on the symbols listed, but you'd also do well to take advantage of Xcode's other code navigation facilities. For example, the file navigator has a clock icon that lets you limit the files displayed to only those that you've used recently. And you shouldn't need to search the navigators constantly for the same things -- instead, open a tab for each file that you're working with.

Comment: Thats is helpful thanks - but it still very difficult with over 80 classes, 20 enums, 15 structs. Is it possible to exclude external header files which I didn't create, leaving only my class, enums, structs? Cheers

Comment: I think not. Xcode can't tell which symbols you want to see and which you don't. What if you wanted to see some of the symbols that you currently want to exclude? I think your best bet is to use the file navigator instead of the symbol navigator. There, you can organize files into groups any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I figured the solution out finally. Instead of having a copy of the external library within my project, if you keep it external, and add the file path to the lib in the xcode build settings:

build settings -> search paths -> header search path

If you add it into here, then the header is included within your project. But the symbols do not appear, and fill up your symbol navigator!